# Getting entire redux state as a separate JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, redux, redux-devtools

I need to get the whole Redux state as a JSON file without payload or action from Redux DevTools, just the state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using React, and have React DevTools installed, there's another way to get the state from within Chrome:

Open React DevTools Components tab and select the top level "Provider":
[image: React DevTools Components Tab]

Then go to the Console tab and paste this into the prompt: `JSON.stringify($r.store.getState())`
[image: $r.store.getState()]

$r is the currently selected component in react devtools

Comment: Accepted this answer, as this one is better than previous

Comment: This worked for me `JSON.stringify($r.props.store.getState())`

Answer (score 11):

State -> Raw -> Copy & Paste

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: This is a valid JS object, but it's not technically valid JSON as the keys need to be strings which need to be surrounded by quotes: https://www.json.org/

Comment: when I paste it into my editor and save as *.json it gets formatted correctly (with quotes, etc) 8)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Redux devTool => state => raw => Copy all the state
2. Open the visual code, create a .json file and paste the state into this new file
3. Install "Prettier" extension.
4. Right click and choose "Format document with..."

[image]

5. Select "Prettier - Code formatter"
   [image]

It's done in my case :D